# How can i catch "UnhandledExceptionCausingProcessCrash" that Azure reports?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am running an app service in Azure. The app crashes and restarts more that 10 times a day.
I have looked at the Availablity and Performance panel under the title "UnhandledExceptionCausingProcessCrash" , but this doesnt provide much useful information.

I have also started Crash Monitor under Diagnostic Tools, it has been going for about 4 hours  and has not created any logs , but i know it has crashed because if i donload the log files i can see exceptions and Process crash.

I am using NHibernate in my app and there was and error as follows:

```
 FaultingExceptionFrame
 HelperMethodFrame
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 ....
```

I suspect that there may be a lock on a table when i run a SQL command, can i get what command is running and if the table is locked ?

When does the Crash Monitor create the files , or do i need to stop monitoring to get the files ?

Do i need to configure the App service to be "Always-On" for the crash dump file to be created ?